# How to change 'nbf' value in JWT token?

Tags: c#, jwt

For some reason, I want to change `nbf` payload value in my JWT token. I am trying to add value but am unable to achieve it.

```
DateTime original = DateTime.Now;
original = original.AddMinutes(-10);
var seconds = original.Subtract(DateTime.MinValue).TotalSeconds;
var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>()
{
    new Claim("email",sresult.Properties["mail"][0].ToString()),
    new Claim("sub", accountName),
    new Claim("myv",seconds.ToString()),
    new Claim("nbf",seconds.ToString()),
```

Where I'm doing mistakes, the `nbf` value doens't get updated with my value. The actual `nbf` value is `1487049869`(system generated datetime) but my value is `63622665869` (-10 minutes less than current datetime).

Comment: @jps :) unix time helped

Answer (score 3):

two things come to my mind:

1. you didn't show much of your code here, so I can't see how the token is generated, but if you have something like this:

   ```
    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_issuer, audienceId, data.Identity.Claims, issued.Value.UtcDateTime, expires.Value.UtcDateTime, signingKey);
   ```

then the fourth parameter is the desired nbf (not before). Actually you don't need to add a nbf claim manually, as it is one of the standard fields in a JWT

2. your timestamp seems odd to me

> my value is 63622665869 (-10 minutes less than current datetime).

the timestamps in JWT are UNIX timestamps counting from 01.01.1970 00:00 UTC: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.4 explains that a numeric date is used for the exp claim (and also for the nbf (not before) and iat (issued at) claims)

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-2 defines the numeric date:

> A JSON numeric value representing the number of seconds from
> 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z UTC until the specified UTC date/time, ignoring
> leap seconds.

so JWT would interpret your value (63622665869)
as 02/14/3986 @ 10:44am (UTC)
or it is not accepted at all.

there are several websites where you can check/convert your timestamp, e.g this one: http://www.unixtimestamp.com/