# node.js - How to validate JWT generated token with Firebase an login?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt

**Aim** :- Trying to provide Token based login to the user with JWT Token

**Things Tried :**

We already have jwt library installed on nodejs Server. So i just added a `firebaseId` as `uid` to it and Generated token.

**Note** :-  JWT Generated by using Firebase secret key.

**Example Token** :-

> eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS4wIiwiaWQiOiI1OTNmYmVkZDEyNzU2MTBmMDA5ZWZiYiIsInN1YiI6Im93bmVycGFyYWRpc2VAZ21haWwuY29tIiwidWlkIjoiZGIxYzE3MzktOTAyZC00MzI0LTk3YzAtYWUyNjYyZWQyNWY0IiwiZmlyc3ROYW1lIjoiUHJhc2FkIiwibGFzdE5hbWUiOiJOdiIsImlhdCI6IjE0OTc4NjgxNzk1MTQiLCJleHAiOiIxNDk5MDc3Nzc5NTE2In0.FGZlgPUYihX_izF4KNGxs1_ku5_4WFgO5agJU9qADes

**Token Decoded** :-

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "id": "593fbedd1275610f009efbb",
  "sub": "ownerparadise@gmail.com",
  "uid": "db1c1739-902d-4324-97c0-ae2662ed25f4",
  "firstName": "Prasad",
  "lastName": "Nv",
  "iat": "1497868179514",
  "exp": "1499077779516"
}
```

When I tried to login with `authWithCustomToken` the above token Raising an error.

```
Error: INVALID_TOKEN: Missing claim 'iat' in auth token.
```

But Already defined `iat` already in the decoded token.

Could you guys suggest any way to verify jwt token with firebase and log in with JWT?

Or Do i Need to Configure Any Option on my Firebase to start accepting JWT Token s ?

Thanks,
Prasad.

Comment: I can't answer your questions regarding firebase, but I see that your timestamps are wrong. (3 digits too long) Pls. read my anser https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42218447/how-to-change-nbf-value-in-jwt-io-token-c-sharp?answertab=oldest#tab-top There you'll find the information you need

Comment: I wonder if my comment/answer was helpful for you. Did you fix the timestamps?

Comment: In fact I did . I used The Right time-stamps instead the above with the New JWT generated No use different errror MAC error ... not feeling right about the approach Any Way Thanks for the advice !!

Comment: you're welcome. Hope someone with more knowledge about firebase can help you.

Comment: Sure Buddy .. Have a Good Day !! Make it to Top 3 percent Good Luck  :-)